# Is there a way to check if SVG is created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm facing an issue where I have to check if all svgs elements (around 15 on one page) is created by a chart plugin. I don't want to hack into that code, because it would probably not work when the plugin gets updated. I want to do this in jQuery (or in plain javascript if necessary)

So I basically want to do something

```
$("svg").bind("load", function() {
    alert('svg has loaded');
});
```

But above does not seem to work. If I understand it correctly SVG is not a part of the actual dom, so that would be the issue then. Is there any way of checking if an SVG has been created?

The dom looks like this:

```
<div id="visualizer-100">
<div id="visualizer-101">
<div id="visualizer-102">
```

When I look in firebug or similar then I see something like this:

```
<div id="visualizer-100">
    <div>
        <div> 
            <svg with all its its attributes...>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason I want to check if SVG is "there" is that I would like to do this:

```
var container = document.getElementById('visualizer-100');
var svgText = container.querySelector('svg').outerHTML;
```

If the SVG is not created, then I get null for the svgText.

Comment: Maybe you can add an onload attribute directly to the svg element.

Comment: @sailens - How do you mean?

Comment: Not the element itself, but you can set onload attributes in the elements inside the svg markup. For example `<image xlink:href="example.png" width="10" height="10" 
       onload="alert('loaded')"/>`

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question at the bottom there then?

Comment: @Shikkediel - nope. it doesn not work...container object works, but SVG is null... I think it's because the SVG is created dynamically after the dom is loaded. (but that's just a guess)

Comment: Could you post a live link? It's hard to imagine what's happening exactly based on the current info.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't for the moment being. Basically I'm using Wordpress and https://sv.wordpress.org/plugins/visualizer/ installed. What I want to do is to save the charts as images but I need to get access to the svg to achieve that (save svg to canvas and save as png from canvas). I'll be back with a testsite as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to listen to the parent element of those SVG 
And then listening for that target load:

```
parentElement.bind('DOMNodeInserted',function(event){ 
     alert(event.target + 'inserted');
});
```

the fJSiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0532h5ey/

As for element loaded, You should target internal SVG nodes.

Comment: Wow. Cool. Thanks a lot! Now I get an alert of each and every element that is created (about 5 different elements) for each chart. Is there a way of checking that all occurences of this parents element is loaded?

Comment: Do you know the exact number of elements to be loaded?  @bestprogrammerintheworld

Comment: No I actually don't (because I havent counted them :-)) but it would make sense to believe that charts of the same chart-type and the same type of info would have exactly the same number of elements and then it would be easy just count them and whenever it reaches to X I would doWhatever(). Awesome!